# What do z${variable} and zfalse in bash script mean?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have an existing script in my Linux host with these statements:

```
local variable=$1
if [ "z${variable}" != "zfalse" ]; then
  local flag="--some_flag"
fi
```

I haven't found an explanation of these "z${variable}" and "zfalse" notation or syntax in my Shell Scripting book. Hope someone can help explain what they mean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what `echo "Hello"` does? How about `echo "zfalse"`?

Comment: Yes. zfalse is not an explicitly defined string in the script. echo "zfalse" returns zfalse.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly defined string"? How do you define a string?

Comment: function run_function 
{
local param=$1
local variable=$2

if [ "z${variable}" != "zfalse" ]; then
  local flag="--some_flag"
fi

…
}

run_function “string 1” false
…
run_function “string 2”
…

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to put a newline in the comment field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do shell script comparisons often use x$VAR = xyes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/174119/608639), [Bash test for empty string with X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6852612/608639), [Portable way to check emptyness of a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900088/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'z' is there to prevent syntax error in case ${variable} evaluates to nothing. If your user does not provide $1 parameter, ${variable} is empty, and without 'z', the if condition would look something like

```
if [ != false ] ...
```

which is syntactically incorrect. With 'z', it becomes:

```
if [ z != zfalse ] ...
```

Comment: That's incorrect. The variable is quoted, so `[ "${variable}" != "false" ]` would work fine even with empty variables.

Comment: @melpomene It's useless today, but the pattern was useful decades ago when some shells handled `""` incorrectly.

Comment: The number of decades we're talking about is relevant. Correct behavior was  standard-mandated in 1992, and widespread well before that.